# Save data within a scene in unity during play mode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to be able to revisit different scenes in a game im making in unity however i want to have the scene be in the same state as when i left it such as having all the enemys dead or the items collected.

how would i go about programming this into unity as currently my entire will be refreshed when it is reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to make a saving system. Because trying to save your current scene as a scene asset may not work well, if the level state is not completely serialized. For example:

> or the items collected.

Item game object will be destroyed and not visible in saved scene. But will it be stored in your inventory, if your items list is not serialized?

So I would definitely make a saving system, even if saving system was not planned for my game. You could use it only for development.
For this you need to find a way of serializing objects that should be serialized and implement deserialization as well.
You can find some information in the internet how to do this.

Here's one of the available solutions:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/complex-save-system-example.897968/

Answer (score 0):

If you are going into a large game you should have a save system to a file and you should retrive the data wherever/whenever you want.

however, if it is a small game. I would suggest you to use playerprefs. simply save all what you need collectables, enemey postions etc... and write a script to call playerpref.

you may want to have look how to use playerfres [here in this link](https://gamedevbeginner.com/how-to-use-player-prefs-in-unity/#:%7E:text=It%20works%20by%20storing%20a,use%20to%20retrieve%20it%20again.)

this is how save load  maybe a location of an enemy

```
public void SaveNumber()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("myNumber", 100);
}
```

Load :

```
public void LoadNumber()
{
    int loadedNumber = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(myNumber);
}
```